# iPhone Core Data Missing Entities

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I've had an app that I've been working on for a while that I originally included Core Data support in, but didn't actually start trying to use it until recently.  Now that I'm actually trying to use Core Data ... it doesn't seem like I can.  When I edit my xcdatamodel to include new (or really, any) entities, I can't seem to actually access those entities in the application itself.  Somewhere along the way, I renamed the project from ProjectTest to CoreDataTest, which I suspect is causing or is related to this problem.  I haven't changed any of the default methods which were generated in the app delegate initially by Xcode (initially 3, but now using 4).

So, I've created a new entity called simply enough TestEntity with a single attribute (String) TestAttribute.

In my app delegate, I've tried a couple of different ways to access the Entity and save a string to it, but all fail.  So I thought I'd walk through all entities thinking I was somehow messing up creating the creation of the NSEntityDescription. I put the following code in to show a listing of all Entities ... and got nothing:

```
NSManagedObjectModel *model = [[self.managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator]
                               managedObjectModel];
NSLog(@"List of Entities:");
for (NSEntityDescription *entity in model)
{
  NSLog(@"Entity: %@", entity);
}
NSLog(@"Done with list");
```

For an output I just get:

```
2011-09-21 14:58:01.955 CoreDataTest[1813:b603] List of Entities:
2011-09-21 14:58:01.955 CoreDataTest[1813:b603] Done with list
```

So ... I've tried cleaning the build.  I've searched through a lot of questions here on SO and more on google, but I can't seem to find anything that solves my problem.  I don't get any actual error messages or uncaught exceptions during a run of the app. Any ideas what could be causing it?  I'm sure it's probably something stupidly simple that I'm overlooking ...

Thanks for any help,

Will

Comment: Are you using the XCode GUI to create your Core Data Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding .entities, i.e.:

```
for (NSEntityDescription *entity in model.entities) { //...
```

See The docs for [NSManagedObjectModel](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectModel_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Also check your model is not null.  Try printing it: `NSLog(@"%@",model);`

Comment: Robert, thanks for the answer, and your second point about checking that the model is not null is the ultimate solution. Boiling down the essentials to put in this question caused me to rethink a few things I was doing in the original project. I was actually referencing an object before it was initialized (not actually shown in the code above) which caused this problem. So in short ... it was my own dumb actions forgetting the order of events which caused my confusion.